# How to change the style of the AutoComplete pop-up of a ComboBox WinForms element?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox, autocomplete

I'm creating a WinForms with a ComboBox, and I want the AutoCompleteMode to be SuggestAppend because there might be a lot of items inside it (AutoCompleteSource = ListItems).

The AutoComplete part works as it should so nothing bad here, but when the AutoComplete pop-up shows up the style is the default one (I guess) while I have changed the style of the ComboBox.

**How can I change the style of this pop-up?** Even only the Font size would be fine, but a complete answer would be better of course.

*Details about style edition of the ComboBox:*
I only changed the Font Size using the Visual Studio Properties window. The code inside my class Form is thus exactly the same as the one for a new Form, just populating the ComboBox for the test :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ComboBox.Items.Add(new string[] {"These", "are", "strings", "for", "test", "purposes"});            
    }
}
```

Comment: how did you change the style? give us please some code to work with. So we can easily pull up a test project on our machines with a little copy pasting ;) this helps us, which helps you

Comment: @MongZhu Actually don't change anything into code, everything using VS properties of the element. I will add precisions about it in my question.

Comment: The [IAutoComplete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shldisp/nn-shldisp-iautocomplete) interface doesn't provide means to *personalize* the AutoComplete pop-up (while it provides a [ACO_WORD_FILTER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shldisp/ne-shldisp-autocompleteoptions) option which can be interesting). You'll have to roll your own (with a standard ListBox, usually).

Comment: @Jimi Mmh, pretty annoying. I'll leave it as it is to save time as UI isn't that important for this program. Thank you for your interest.